# What is the recommended way to add Help to my MS Project VSTO add-in?

Tags: vsto, ms-project

I can't seem to find a simple answer. Is there a recommended way to do this? I'd like to build my help files as I build out my functionality.

Answer (score 0):

VSTO doesn't have extensible Help. You have to add it wherever it makes the most sense for you: in the ribbon, a task pane, the backstage (File menu), context menus, etc.

Comment: I saw something about .chm applications, but I can't get straight how (or if) to use it. Or I guess I could just put a side pane up and link in a web page, but some of our clients might be behind firewalls that don't allow them out to the web.

Comment: You could store the chm locally, even as a project resource.